# Clickable Title in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am implementing the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and I'd like to have a draggable titles. The `title` of each fragment can be interactive just like the pager effect. The user can drag or browse `title` of all fragments without affecting the *current view* by the time the user stops or select a specific `title` then that's the time the view gets updated. I am not sure how to do this, is this possible. Please share your insights and opinions about this. Thanks

```
@Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Title";

            case 1:
                return "Title";
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my research, the `PagerTitleStrip` does is not interactive, I tried using the `PagerTabStrip` but does not support dragging or browsing of `titles`, I strongly recommend using actionsherlock if you want to implement similar functionality as I want.